# How to detect if a MSMessage is sent to someone who does not have iOS10?

Tags: ios, ios10, imessage

I created an iMessage app for iOS10. My app can send messages to non iOS10 users but it does not have any interest (it just sends a non interactive image).

Is there a way to detect that my the remote participant in my MSConversation does not have iOS10 and display a more user friendly message?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to know if the iMessage was received or something by the non iMessage app? In that case it's not directly possible within iMessage app as MSConversation is only available in iMessage extensions. You'll have to do this with a server side ;)

Edit:

On earlier version, iOS will display a placeholder message indeed, but there are actually no ways to handle that, has the SDK is not available for these versions. So the answer is unfortunately still NO, Sorry :/

Comment: can you give more details on how you would do it server side?

Comment: Hey matt, sorry my bad, I think this is actually not possible :/ iMessages send to another application which is not iMessage won't be readable because it's an Apple SDK. By the way I don't really understand how you want to do that? iMessages can only by deliver to iPhones and iMessage app, what do you actually want to do?

Comment: haha my bad actually, I thought the message had been sent outside of an iMessage conversation but it had been sent to someone with iOS version < iOS10. I will edit my question, sorry.

Comment: It's sadly. MSMessage  sent to iOS9 will be showed the URL link only. Not the caption, summaryText, or other text.... Only insertText with pure text works on both iOS10/iOS9. However, it's ugly and miss functions of MSMessage on iOS10.